# Checking authentication state with AngularFire2 v4

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

I am trying to encapsulate AngularFire2 v4 authentication state on a service class so I have a single way to check if the user is authenticated.

I'm following the v4 upgrade guide at: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md

Here is the relevant portion of my service class:

```js
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(
    private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {
    this.user = this.angularFireAuth.authState;
  }

  get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    let authenticated = false;
    this.user.take(1).subscribe(user => authenticated = user !== null);
    return authenticated;
  }

}
```

The problem I'm having is that `authenticated` always returns `false`, even when `user` is not null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning `false` because the callback inside `subscribe` will be called synchronously if there are values to read in the observable or asynchronously when there are no values yet to be read. In your case there are not, so you are actually returning the initial `false` without waiting for those values.

You could do something like this:

```
get isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.user.last().map(user => user !== null);
}
```

Now, to use that getter in your template, you should use the [`async`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html) pipe. Something like: `*ngIf="(isAuthenticated | async)"`.

Note I also changed the `.take(1)` for [`.last()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/last.html), which I think makes more sense here.

To show exactly what is happening here.

**Observable being called synchronously:**

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.range(0, 2);

function isAuthenticated() {
  let authenticated = false;
  
  source.last().subscribe((x) => {
    console.log('New value: ' + x);
        
    authenticated = true;
  });
    
  return authenticated;
}

console.log(isAuthenticated())
console.log(isAuthenticated())
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

**Observable being called asynchronously:**

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.range(0, 2).delay(1000);

function isAuthenticated() {
  let authenticated = false;
  
  source.last().subscribe((x) => {
    console.log('New value: ' + x);
        
    authenticated = true;
  });
    
  return authenticated;
}

console.log(isAuthenticated())
console.log(isAuthenticated())
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Danziger, that got me going, and thanks for the explanation. Switching the User to an observable in AngularFire2 has made things a bit more difficult for my needs unfortunately.